# Cannot connect to User-PC in SQL Server 2008 Express?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-express

I want to connect to a SQL Server 2008 Express but I get this error - how to solve it?

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to DHARMARAJ-PC.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read and follow: [How to Troubleshoot Connecting to the SQL Server Database Engine](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2102.how-to-troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine.aspx)

> This is an exhaustive list of troubleshooting techniques to use when
>   you cannot connect to the SQL Server Database Engine.